# Найти самую длинную последовательность повторяющихся чисел в списке

Tags: c++, списки

**Задание:** *"Создать однонаправленный или двунаправленный список и найти самую длинную последовательность повторяющихся чисел в списке, сохранить повторяющееся значение и количество повторений"*.

Список вроде создал, да и на примере массивов понятно, как выполнить вторую (интересующую) часть задания, но вот с реализацией алгоритма под списки возникли трудности. Проблема в том, что я знаю, как написать код для нахождения повторяющихся значений в массиве, а как это делается для списков - не имею понятия.

Буду рад любой помощи, ибо уже немного отчаялся найти решение :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int size = 8;

struct Node
{
    int Data;
    Node *next; 
    Node *prev; 
};

int main()
{
    Node *Start = NULL;
    Node *End = NULL;
    Node *Current = NULL;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < size)
        {  // Создаем
            Current = new Node;
            Current -> Data = rand() % 5 + 1;
            Current -> prev = NULL;
            Current -> next = NULL;

            // Заполняем
            if (Start == NULL)
                Start = End = Current;
            else
            {
                End -> next = Current;
                Current -> prev = End;
                End = Current;
            }                        
            i++;
        }

    // Выводим
    Current = Start;
    while (Current)
    {
        cout << Current -> Data << endl;
        Current = Current -> next;
    }

    // Удаляем
    Current = End;          
    while (Current)
    {                  
        Node *temp = Current;
        Current = Current -> prev;                        
        delete temp;
    }
    Start = End = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Напишите, в чем конкретно проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что я знаю, как написать код для нахождения повторяющихся значений в массиве, а как это делается для списков - не имею понятия. Могу прикрепить тот код, что начирикал якобы для массива и от которого пытался отталкиваться.

Comment: Тот код, что у Вас в вопросе - не компилируется. Что такое b[i]?

Comment: Прошу прощения, строчка с cout осталась от попытки с массивами. Убрал. Сейчас должно корректно работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, набросал нечто такое:

```
int elem_curr = Start->Data;
int elem_prev = Start->Data;
std::size_t length_curr = 1;
std::size_t length_prev = 1;
for(Current = Start; Current != nullptr; Current = Current->next)
{
    if(Current == Start) continue;
    if(elem_curr == Current->Data) length_curr++;
    else
    {
        if(length_curr > length_prev)
        {
            elem_prev = elem_curr;
            length_prev = length_curr;
        }
        elem_curr = Current->Data;
        length_curr = 1;
    }
}

if(length_curr > length_prev)
{
    elem_prev = elem_curr;
    length_prev = length_curr;  
}

std::cout << elem_prev << ' ' << length_prev << std::endl;
```

И в начале функции `main` добавьте строчку `srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));` для рандомайзера

По коду - оптимизируйте немного, я так совсем грубо накидал, только ради основной идеи - проход по циклу + поиск подпоследовательности. Например, строчку с *continue* можно "замять" при небольших дополнительных действиях и проверку после цикла на посл., которая в конце списка - тоже можете организовать покрасивее в цикле. Удачи.

Comment: Ух ты, огромное Вам спасибо за помощь. Даже и не ожидал, что вообще кто-нибудь поможет, да еще и так быстро. 

Еще раз спасибо :*

И удачи в учебе (согласно профилю) ^^

Answer (score 0):

Цикл по списку на C:

```
for (Item *item = start; item != NULL; item = item->next) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Участник задал вопрос не относительно цикла, а относительно того, как искать наиболее длинную подпосл в списке

Comment: @Jenssen, самую длинную последовательность повторяющихся чисел искать так же, как в массиве, только цикл по списку.